# Including a static library in a C project (Eclipse)

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, static-libraries

I'm currently developing an application using SDL. In order to utilize it, I have already added the library and header files in the project's settings under `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Libraries/Includes`. However, when I try to build a test program like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I get this beautiful error message during the link process:

> d:/programme/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
>   C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to`WinMain@16'

Which is rather weird, given that the directory C:\MinGW doesn't even exist at all.

The command used for linking is this one:
gcc "-LD:\Programme\SDL\lib" -o test.exe test.o -lsdl

After two hours of trying to get a library link to work, I'm pretty confused and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are building a `Windows GUI` application, which requires a `WinMain`, while your code only provides a `main` function which would be for console applications.

So if this is supposed to be a console application, you must adjust your linker settings accordingly, or you must declare a `WinMain`.